# How to set nginx upstream module response to client synchronously

Tags: nginx, buffer, reverse-proxy, synchronous

I'm set up a live broadcast website. I use nginx as reverse proxy, and deploy multiple flv-live-stream process behind nginx(binary program writen by C++). In my flv-live-stream program. Clients maintain long connection with nginx. I count video frame that alreay sent to predict whether the client play smoothly.

But I found there is a strange buffer in upstream module. Even if the client 100% loss packets, back-end process can still send to nginx for 2~3 seconds, almost 2.5~3MBytes.

If there is a method that response can pass to a client synchronously, as soon as it is received from the back-end. And when nginx is unable to send data to client(exp. client loss packets...), nginx donot accept data from the back-end immediately.

I'm already set

```
listen 80 sndbuf=64k rcvbuf=64k;
proxy_buffering off;
fastcgi_buffering off;
```

Anyone can help? thanks!